# python ssl certificate error while trying youtube api on mac virtualenv

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, virtualenv, youtube-data-api, python-3.7

After long hours of banging my head against Mac system and trying to understand which I don't know, I sort of have given up. But I am still trying to find an answer to it.
My problem is: I am straight away trying to hit a simple youtube API request in python. 
(Note: I am not trying to hit it through requests so please do not answer saying, pass the karwgs: verify to false).
I also updated certificates, I hit commands and have tried to update, install openssl, ssl, certifi, and what not but the thing is it's just doesn't work.
Now Since I guess I lack knowledge of the system but my question is that why am i getting this error:

```
[![ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'api%20key%201.googleapis.com'.][1]][1]
```

All I am trying to do is just like this:

```
youtube = build(API_NAME, API_VERSION, developerKey=API_KEY)
```

Earlier I thought it's something related to my virtual environment which I created and maybe it is because of that as well, which brings me to my next question and which is why do when I go into "apiclient" from my ide, it takes me to a file which is located at somewhere usr\local\Cellar\Frameworks...\python..  because according to my understanding I think usr\local\Cellar on MAC is for brew installations. But anyway my main question is that how do I resolve this ssl certificate error, so if anyone is able to help me then please, I'll be grateful!

Answer (score 0):

%20 is hex of whitespace character - wich would make the requested DNS name "apikey1.googleapis.com" wich is an illegal DNS name (according to DNS RFCs each label is only allowed to have a-z A-Z 0-9 "-" and "_")
I don't know if a wildcard certificate would solve this as it depends on the TLS implementation how labels/hostnames verified.
So, as somewhere the hostname is set wrong, I guess there're a few more lines of code needed to figure out the issue than the one you posted.
Here's the example from reference page https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.channels.list
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import googleapiclient.discovery

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    DEVELOPER_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY"

    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, developerKey = DEVELOPER_KEY)

    request = youtube.channels().list(
        part="id"
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Give it a try and see if the issue still exists. If so maybe some issue in the lib where hostname was set wrong. If the issue is resolved then some in your current code mess up the hostname.

Matt

Comment: I actually figured out the error which I was having. Thanks for your response. I will post the answer, just in case, if someone else is stuck with this

Answer (score 0):

After 4 hours of excruciating pain and then running the same code in my friend's system I figured out that it was because of the service name in api_service_name field. It is confusing though cause in case of API_NAME I assumed I had to put the name in Google console which is not the case. 
I am answering for someone who is having the same issue as me.

**Change your api_service_name or API_NAME to "youtube"**

Hope this helps somebody